# Where do I save .env file?

Tags: python, instagram

I'm trying to load my .env file(enviroment variable file). So I can put my instagram API credentials accordingly. I created a .env file where my views.py file is located at. Which would be main/project/user/views.py.

.env

```
CLIENT_ID=I replace this with actual client ID provided by instagram
CLIENT_SECRET=I replace this with actual clien secrent provided by instagram
SECRET_KEY=same here
REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:5000/instagram_callback
```

views.py

```
instaConfig = {
    'client_id':os.environ.get('CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret':os.environ.get('CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect_uri' : os.environ.get('REDIRECT_URI')
}
api = InstagramAPI(**instaConfig)
```

This doesn't seem to do the magic. As client_id is returned None when I actually make calls using API.